# How to install two different version of dart for flutter and aqueduct in a macos

Tags: flutter, dart, aqueduct

Currently I have dart installed with flutter, versions as below:

```
Flutter 1.23.0-18.1.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 198df796aa (2 weeks ago) • 2020-10-15 12:04:33 -0700
Engine • revision 1d12d82d9c
Tools • Dart 2.11.0 (build 2.11.0-213.1.beta)
```

I was mainly working with Mobile App frontend development, therefore this setup was good for me.

But for backend database development I started learning Aqueduct (https://aqueduct.io/docs/getting_started/). I noticed that aqueduct 3.3.0+1 (which is the current stable version of aqueduct) only works with dart <2.8.0.

Therefore, I wondering if I can have two versions of dart installed in my mac.
If so how I can do it?
And how to switch or select different versions of dart for flutter and aquedart when I am working with them separately or at the same time (if that is possible)?

Edit: I am doing this because I am getting an error when I run `aqueduct create project`. Any solution?

```
-- Aqueduct CLI Version: 3.3.0+1
*** Uncaught error
    Bad state: No element
  **** Stacktrace
  * #0      ListMixin.firstWhere (dart:collection/list.dart:150:5)
  * #1      CLIAqueductGlobal.aqueductPackageRef (package:aqueduct/src/cli/commands/create.dart:342:10)
  * #2      CLIAqueductGlobal.templateDirectory (package:aqueduct/src/cli/commands/create.dart:347:12)
  * #3      CLIAqueductGlobal.getTemplateLocation (package:aqueduct/src/cli/commands/create.dart:351:12)
  * #4      CLITemplateCreator.handle (package:aqueduct/src/cli/commands/create.dart:51:27)
  * #5      CLICommand.process (package:aqueduct/src/cli/command.dart:159:20)
  * <asynchronous suspension>
  * #6      CLICommand.process (package:aqueduct/src/cli/command.dart:135:12)
  * #7      main (file:///C:/Users/dos/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/aqueduct-3.3.0+1/bin/aqueduct.dart:9:27)
  * #8      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
  * #9      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
  ****
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I faced with the EDIT where I get an error when I run `aqueduct create project` is due to not setting up pub properly in the first place.

If you are facing this problem make use to

1. Insert dart-sdk into your path environment variable. for more information follow first few minutes of this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdcJ2PAzXWs&ab_channel=NickManning. This allows you to use `pub`.
2. If you have properly followed above step then you can Run `pub global activate aqueduct` NOT `flutter pub global activate aqueduct` and later create the project without anyone problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. Aqueduct and Flutter handles Dart version lower than 3.0.0 in pubsbpec.yaml

I am on a dev project with my brother and I am using this with latest working aqueduct

```
Flutter (Channel master, 1.24.0-4.0.pre.138, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2
    darwin-x64, locale en-BR)
```

You don't need to worry with flutter's dart sdk, it handles it alone

To user a new version of dart separate from flutter is just using Homebrew

```
brew tap dart-lang/dart
brew install dart
```

In your flutter project you override in settings.json inside .vscode folder with the new dart path (I am using flutter_master build, so I had to override it too instead of flutter stable)

```
{
  "dart.flutterSdkPath": "~/Library/flutter_master/bin",
  "dart.sdkPath": "/usr/local/bin/dart"
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Update your pubspec.yaml with the following

```
dependencies:
  aqueduct: 3.3.0+1

dependency_overrides:
  postgres: 2.2.0
```

The error you mention happens the same with me, I forgot to mention it.
The issue I found a long time ago in [this github thread](https://github.com/stablekernel/aqueduct/issues/844#issuecomment-635372704)

Comment: I am doing this due to the error mentioned in the EDIT of the main post.
-- Aqueduct CLI Version: 3.3.0+1
*** Uncaught error
    Bad state: No element

Comment: did you get any error when you run aqueduct create project? as in the error in the EDIT

Comment: This is a postgre plugin error compatibility, you have to override a new version in pubspec.yaml

Comment: I updated the answer with new details to fix your problem